# Passing an gets.chomp as an argument

Tags: ruby, arguments, seek

```
input_file = ARGV.first

def print_all(f)
    puts f.read
end

def rewind(f)
    f.seek(0)
end

def print_a_line(line_count, f)
    puts "#{line_count}, #{f.gets.chomp}"
end

current_file = open(input_file)

puts "First let's print the whole file:¥n"

print_all(current_file)

puts "Let's rewind kind a like a tape"

rewind(current_file)

puts "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line += 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

I'm sure there is a kinda similar post to this, but my question is a bit different. As seen above, the print_a_line method got two params that are line_count and f.

1) As I understood, line_count argument only serves as a variable which is current_line and it is just an integer. How does it relate to the rewind(f) method because when I run the code, the method print_a_line shows this:

```
1, Hi
2, I'm a noob
```

where 1 is the first line and 2 is the second. line_count is just a number, how does ruby know that 1 is line 1 and 2 is line 2?

2) Why use gets.chomp in method print_a_line? If I pass just f like this

```
def print_a_line(line_count, f)
    puts "#{line_count}, #{f}"
end
```

I'll get a crazy result which is

```
1, #<File:0x007fccef84c4c0>
2, #<File:0x007fccef84c4c0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [`IO#gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-gets) reads next line from readable I/O stream(in this case it's a file) and returns a `String` object when reading successfully and not reached end of the file. And, [`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) removes carriage return characters from `String` object.

So when you have a file with content such as:

```
This is file content.
This file has multiple lines.
```

The code will print:

```
1, This is file content.
2, This file has multiple lines.
```

In the second case, you're passing file object itself and not reading it. Hence you see those objects in output.